# Get ListView Item content when clicking it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a `ListView` that has items from the array i.e `String[] statesList = {"Adult 1", "Adult 2","Adult 3","Child 1","Child 2","Child 1","Child 2","Child 2"};`

Now I want to hide a `TextView` if the item is clicked apart from Adult.

This is my function that I have written for populating the data in the listview

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    showPassengerListView();
}


    private void showPassengerListView() {


            String[]  passengerList ={"Adult 1", "Adult 2","Adult 3","Child 1","Child 2","Child 1","Child 2","Child 2"};
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, passengerList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
if((passengerList[position].contains("Child"))|| (passengerList[position].contains("Infant"))){
                    dateofBirth.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else{
                    dateofBirth.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                }
        });
          **passengerInformationPopup()**
    }

public void passengerInformationPopup() {
        final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(IweenBookingPage.this,R.style.Dialog_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.passenger_details_dialog); 
        String[] tittlearray ={"Mr.","Mrs.","Ms"};
        Spinner tittleSpinner = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Tittle);
         dateofBirth = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dateofBirth);
        dateofBirth.setClickable(true);

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tittlearray); 

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        tittleSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

And i am getting the exception :

```
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at com.android.iweentravel.Book$5.onItemClick(Book.java:184)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1114)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2937)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3695)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
08-16 15:51:55.727: E/AndroidRuntime(15553):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How to check which item has been clicked from the ListView? On the basis of the item clicked I have to show/hide a TextView . Main question is how to identify . The items will be dynamic in the ListView .But have like Adult,Child ,Infant.

Comment: `TextView#setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

Comment: you want to delete the item from listview or hide?

Comment: Can't you get item text inside `onItemClick()`?

Comment: make sure dateofBirth is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide a TextView like that

```
TextView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

or

```
TextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

depending on what you want to do.

A simple way of **identifying an item inside your onItemClick() method** would be:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 // for example like that
                 if(passengerlist[position].contains("Adult)") // do something

                 // or like that
                 TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);

                 if(tv.getText().toString().contains("Adult)") // do something
            }
        });
```

Comment: i know how to hide and show. how could i identify that the item has been clicked apart from the Adult 1,Adult 2,Adult 3.This array will be created dynamically.

Comment: Updated my question as per u r suggestion getting exception

Comment: I suppose your "dateofBirth" variable (TextView?) is causing the Nullpointer. Is it initialized correctly? Please post the code where it is initialized.

Comment: phil i have updated my code please see what i can do .what u r saying is correct .So i could i fix this

Comment: u r right dateofBirth is getting initialzed in the passengerInformationPopup and i am trying to acess it before

Answer (score 0):

In your `onItemClick` try somthing like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```